# jquery radio button not refreshing

Tags: jquery, radio-button

This will be a quick question I'm sure for I'm sure I'm having a brain fart here.

Goal. On load select one of the two radio buttons.

Problem. Visually it does not show.

I've tried sepreatly and at the same time the two lines of code.

`$("#sSexFemale").attr("checked", true);`

`$("#sSexFemale").prop("checked", true);`

The first line changes

`<input type="radio" name="sSex" id="sSexFemale" value="0">`

into

`<input type="radio" name="sSex" id="sSexFemale" value="0" checked="checked">`

but the radio button is still not checked visually. If I manually changed the file so that the html starts with the second line then I see the radio button is selected. I did some research and I found that someone was saying to use.

`$('#sSexFemale').buttonset("refresh");`

but this generates the following error.

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on buttonset prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

This must be something simple that I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the code works fine, there's something else going wrong => http://jsfiddle.net/4onxr3am/

Comment: Could you point me in the direction as to where to start debugging this (very very vague question I know).

Comment: do you have other jQuery codes? do they work alright? also have you tested it in other browsers?

Comment: Other jquery code on the page works. I'm using Chrome and tried it in Opera and same result.